# Problem with submitting Interactive forms created in Indesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I made a questionnaire in Indesign and when I open it in Adobe reader and attempt to submit it I get an error message saying that action isn't permitted.  I came across something else that said you had to somehow connect a mail client like Outlook to it in order for it to send properly.

It's already going to be enough "extra work" for my clients to have to update to the latest Adobe Reader, as I'll be suggesting on the Introduction page, I don't want to have to walk them through connecting outlook to Acrobat as well because everybody isn't that tech savvy... I want them to be able to just fill it out and send it to me.

Is it possible to do this through Gmail or Yahoo?  Could there be another issue causing a problem as well?  Or is there a way where they can fill it out and save it then send it to me as an attachment?  Because it also says to print it out if you want the results for your own records because it won't save it.  How can I resolve this issue?  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Newer versions of Acrobat/Reader do support webmail services, such as GMail. It would, however, have to be the end user's task to properly configure their mail connection. Another approach would, however, be to not use eMail as submit medium, but submit the data to a server, which then either uses s formmail script to pass the data to eMail, or has another processing script. When selectinog submitting as HTML POST, standard web form handling scripts can be used.

Comment: thanks.  I found instructions for it and it seems simple enough, I can just save that pic from their site and add it in on the instructions page.  I have another question I need help with but I think the forum would prefer I make a new topic about it than carry on here so if you know this stuff pretty well PLEASE look for it and see if you can help... I'd appreciate it lol.